# Calculating Fiscal Month

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time, date

I've seen a number of calculations for fiscal year and quarter, but am hoping someone can help me a calculated column for fiscal months.  Our company's fiscal months run from the 29th through the 28th. Using a date and time field, I want to be able to return a result of YYYY-MM.  (So, for example, if the date is 11/28/2019, the fiscal month would be 2019-11.  If the date is 11/29/2019, the fiscal month would be 2019-12.)

I'm working in Sharepoint 2013.

I have no idea where to even start on this one. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(AND(DAY([MyDate]) > 28, MONTH([MyDate]) = 12), YEAR([MyDate]) + 1, YEAR([MyDate]))&"-"&IF(DAY([MyDate]) > 28,IF(MONTH([MyDate]) = 12, 1, MONTH([MyDate]) +1), MONTH([MyDate])))
```

Just change [MyDate] to whatever is your date column's name.